# how to pop a dialog from a website meanwhile by refreshing this website,the dialog will NOT disappear?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the detail of the question:

There ia a website called A. By pressing the button on the website A, a dialog shows up.After 10 seconds,the dialog disappears.**My question is:The website A actually keeps refreshing itself every 3 seconds,so everytime I press the button,the dialog can only be shown for less than 3 seconds because the dialog frame will immediately disappear after the website refreshing itself.**

The website A has to keep refresh itself to get the newest information,the time intercal can not be changed,which is 3 sec.But I want to keep the dialog for 10 seconds,long enough for the user to see.

The reason why I didn't use AJAX is that I used python to creat html when there is new information.But after html created,the previous website can NOT discover such change of html.Only by refreshing itself all the time can the browser load the newest html.But I'll consider use AJAX if there is no other ways.

Also I found some other resourece code from the web but all of those dialogs will disappear after refreshing.

Can anybody have any idea to share? I truly appreciate your help.Thanks very much!

Here is my code:

```
 <html>  <head>  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">  
 <title>JavaScript Closing dialog auto.</title>  <meta
 http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html;charset=gb2312">  </head>
 <body>     <input type="button" value="Pop" onClick="Alert('Close
 after 10 sec')">    <script>

function Alert(str) {  
     var msgw,msgh,bordercolor;  
     msgw=350;  
     msgh=80; 
     titleheight=25;  
     bordercolor="#336699";  
     titlecolor="#99CCFF";  
     var sWidth,sHeight;  


 sWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;  
 sHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;      
 var bgObj=document.createElement("div");  
 bgObj.setAttribute('id','alertbgDiv');  
 bgObj.style.position="absolute";  
 bgObj.style.top="0";  
 bgObj.style.background="#E8E8E8";  
 bgObj.style.filter="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=3,opacity=25,finishOpacity=75";  
 bgObj.style.opacity="0.6";  
 bgObj.style.left="0";  
 bgObj.style.width = sWidth + "px";  
 bgObj.style.height = sHeight + "px";  
 bgObj.style.zIndex = "10000";  
 document.body.appendChild(bgObj);  

 var msgObj = document.createElement("div")  
 msgObj.setAttribute("id","alertmsgDiv");  
 msgObj.setAttribute("align","center");  
 msgObj.style.background="white";  
 msgObj.style.border="1px solid " + bordercolor;  
 msgObj.style.position = "absolute";  
 msgObj.style.left = "50%";  
 msgObj.style.font="12px/1.6em Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";  

 msgObj.style.marginLeft = "-225px";  
 msgObj.style.top = document.body.scrollTop+(window.screen.availHeight/2)-150 +"px";  
 msgObj.style.width = msgw + "px";  
 msgObj.style.height = msgh + "px";  
 msgObj.style.textAlign = "center";  
 msgObj.style.lineHeight ="25px";  
 msgObj.style.zIndex = "10001";  
 document.body.appendChild(msgObj);  

 var title=document.createElement("h4");  
 title.setAttribute("id","alertmsgTitle");  
 title.setAttribute("align","left");  
 title.style.margin="0";  
 title.style.padding="3px";  
 title.style.background = bordercolor;  
 title.style.filter="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(startX=20, startY=20, finishX=100, finishY=100,style=1,opacity=75,finishOpacity=100);";  
 title.style.opacity="0.75";  
 title.style.border="1px solid " + bordercolor;  
 title.style.height="18px";  
 title.style.font="12px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";  
 title.style.color="white";  
 title.innerHTML="Info";  
 document.getElementById("alertmsgDiv").appendChild(title);  

 var txt = document.createElement("p");  
 txt.setAttribute("id","msgTxt");  
 txt.style.margin="16px 0";  
 txt.innerHTML = str;  
 document.getElementById("alertmsgDiv").appendChild(txt);  

 window.setTimeout("closewin()",10000);   


}  
 function closewin() {  
     document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("alertbgDiv"));  
     document.getElementById("alertmsgDiv").removeChild(document.getElementById("alertmsgTitle"));  
     document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("alertmsgDiv"));  
 }
 </script>
 </body>   
 </html>
```

Comment: I think you should use `ajax` to get newest information, avoid reloading the page

Comment: If your site keeps refreshing itself, like w3schools, there's a problem with your code. AJAX, AJAX, AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need ajax,it can help you refresh data but not refresh the whole page A.
Here's intro about js   [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)!
you can also use jquery to solve it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)!